# Who were the Furlings?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

In the episode of Stargate SG-1 called "The Fifth Race", there are 4 advanced races which are listed, namely the Asgard, the Ancients, the Nox, and the Furlings. The Asgard and the Ancients were extensively mentioned, the Nox had a few episodes that they were mentioned, but so far as I know, the Furlings never appeared, nor were heard from. Who are they?

Comment: The top four Google results for "furlings" are wiki pages that answer this. Are you looking for more information than that?

Comment: *"So much more to learn. Can you not ask the other aliens, the Asgard and the Nox, what they know of these Furlings?" "We've tried," Daniel replied. "We get the same 'you're too young' or 'you're not yet ready' reply. General," he added, turning to Hammond, "I can't categorically state that the Furlings built the skull network, but a race that advanced would surely keep an eye on the planets they seeded - unless, like the Ancients, they abandoned the galaxy.*  -SG1: #4 City of the Gods.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

The Furlings never did make an appearance on SG-1, but there was mention of them in several episodes, and Furling ruins were found and explored.

> The length of time that the Furling nature has remained a mystery in the series has given the producers the opportunity to tease fans with a running gag. When Executive Producer Robert C. Cooper was asked "Will we ever meet the Furlings?", his answer was "Who says we haven't?"

from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Furling_%28Stargate%29#Furlings)

There is also a lot of information on the [sg1 wiki](http://www.stargate-sg1-solutions.com/wiki/Furlings).

Comment: The furlings make a pretty funny appearance in the 200th episode, totally what I envisioned.

Comment: I actually imagined that the creature that kidnaps Daniel Jackson in the season 1 episode 'Fire and Water' to be a Furling - advanced technology coupled with hatred of Goa'uld. But this is just my own theory, not grounded in any rumour or fact.

Comment: yes, the 200th episode, "Wormhole Xtreme!" featured the furlings in the TV show within a TV show parody of itself.  It was a pretty brilliant episode, depicting the furlings like ewoks.

Comment: @horuskol No, that was an Ohne: http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Ohnes

Comment: @Daniel - thanks, didn't realise there were sources outside of the TV series

Answer (score 1):

Over the entirety of the Stargate franchise to-date, only the Furlings remain mentioned but unseen. We have seen The Asgard (frequently), The Nox (more than once), and yes even the Ancients (Atlantis). The one depiction of the Furlings in the SG-1 episode "200" as Ewok-like is a fantasy sequence, so the actual Furling race does remain without any true depiction. The limited mention of them as "one of the four great races" is really about all we know of them, and probably all we ever will.